# can't test RESTful webservices in Netbeans 7.3, how to get rid of extra "/" on path

Tags: java, rest, netbeans, jboss

maybe stupid question, but I'll try anyway:

I am using Netbeans 7.3 and I would like to test RESTful webservices from IDE.

Once I right click on my service and say 'test Resource Uri', I get the following message:

Unable to open resource URL:

```
http://localhost:8080//ads-api/rs/ads
```

ads-api is the name of my war file

For some reason, Netbeans is adding extra "/" into the path, right after the port number.

Even if I specify path as ads-api/rs in configuration, it is always overwritten by /ads-api/rs. So, I guess, I should get rid of "/" in `http://localhost:8080/` but I don't know where to find it (it's JBoss 4.2 running from command line, visible in Netbeans though)

Can anyone help me? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the URL of the webservice.

Comment: http://localhost:8080//ads-api/rs/ads

Comment: No, no that. Please, post the mapping of the webservice.

Comment: we're using javax.ws.rs annotations, if that helps

Answer (score 1):

The double slash is not the problem as you can reproduce here:

http://news.yahoo.com/world/

http://news.yahoo.com//world/

Both links work fine. So either there is a problem with your JBoss-Server or more likely in the rest configuration in your project. You could try to let Netbeans create the rest endpoint automatically for you with the wizard based on an entity class or a database table. So you can have a look on a working solution, just for learning.